# Why does this Vim command wipe all characters from my terminal?

Tags: vim, terminal

I have this function in my .vimrc, which I got [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Setting_file_attributes_without_reloading_a_buffer)

```
function! SetExecutableBit()
  let fname = expand("%:p")
  checktime
  execute "au FileChangedShell " . fname . " :echo"
  silent !chmod a+x %
  checktime
  execute "au! FileChangedShell " . fname
endfunction
command! Xbit call SetExecutableBit()
```

When I run `:call SetExecutableBit()`, it works as expected. But when I run `:Xbit`, all characters disappear from my term (but not in Gvim). I've reproduced this on both gnome-terminal and urxvt. If I attempt to highlight some text with the mouse or `ggVG`, that text will reappear.

"Before" screenshot:

[image]

Screenshot of the term after running `:Xbit`:

[image]

Screenshot after selecting some text:

[image]

---

Update, since this error happens with `--noplugin` but does *not* happen with `-u NONE`, it must be something in my .vimrc file: https://gist.github.com/dbb/5373175

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably just a matter of redrawing the screen. Try adding a `:redraw` to your function. If needed, appending a `!` to this command will clear the screen first.

```
function! SetExecutableBit()
  let fname = expand("%:p")
   ...
  execute "au! FileChangedShell " . fname
  redraw
endfunction
```

[`:h :redraw`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#%3aredraw)

Comment: Unfortunately, `:redraw` doesn't seem to do anything. Also, when I call the function directly (i.e. `:callSetExecutableBit()`, the error doesn't occur; it's only when I run the command `:Xbit` which in turn calls the function. So even if redrawing was the problem, I don't think it would help me here.

Comment: @Daniel certainly it's not the problem, but it may solve the problem. What if you append it to the command definition? `:command! Xbit call SetExecutableBit() <bar> redraw`

Comment: Sorry, I screwed up. It actually did work when I used `redraw!` at the end of the function (I forgot the ! the first time).

It's still puzzling to me why it only happened when calling the command.

Comment: @Daniel No worries, I'm happy that it solved. Well, actually I can't tell you exactly what causes this, but I'm my experience yes it happens. Depending on your set of plugins and general configuration you may need to occasionally redraw the screen by yourself…